# Instagram API for ADS posts not working

Tags: api, instagram, ads, instagram-api

I get instagram post details (likes, comments) by using the media endpoint:

```
$data1 = file_get_contents("https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/$media_id/likes?access_token=$access_token");
```

This works for normal posts from my feed, but when I input the $media_id for an instagram post that is an AD I always get invalid media id

```
{
  "meta":  {
    "error_type": "APINotFoundError",
    "code": 400,
    "error_message": "invalid media id"
  }
}
```

Are ads treated as different types of posts or the API is unable to retrieve any details from them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the ads are treated like a different type of post and can only be managed or fully read by means of the Facebook APIs. Try the [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api), the [Marketing API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-apis) or the Business Manager API, that's where I got the most useful tips and results.

(sorry, dont have enough rep to post more than two links. But don't worry, you'll find it on google in a heartbeat)

Answer (score 1):

Instagram ADS API has been integrated into Facebook Marketing API.

All the details are here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/instagramads/ads_management/v2.6

There is a workaround to get some details on an AD. If you query the oembed endpoint, like this: https://api.instagram.com/oembed/?url=https://www.instagram.com/p/BAZV-jVlFGp/ you get some data.
I wasn't able to get any comments though.